# Transfer Ubuntu server 10.04 to another 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer

I am totally new to Linux administration and now I have big problem. I have old server with some sites, databases, programs etc that is Ubuntu 10.04. Because of too much users I rented new better and faster server but with Ubuntu 13.04. So my question is: Does anyone know easy way to transfer all server data, sites, databases, mail server etc etc on new Ubuntu 13.04 server? My hosting provider will do IP changes when I ask them but I need to transfer everything else alone and they don't provide software support.

Comment: What services do you actually use? Which servers? Which web servers? Which databases? In most cases, it should work if you just copy the data to the corresponding directories on the new setup and also copy the configuration files. Since this is a much newer OS than your old one, some details might change but most should still work. I recommend you make a backup of your new server and then start copying files across. Post back here when/if you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

for *Debian* i would only recommend to upgrade from one stable release to the next, and *never* to try to skip an inbetween release (even if this means multiple upgrade steps).

```
# aptitude full-upgrade
```

Debian goes through a lot of hoops in order to make upgrades from one release to the next as painless as possible.
even so, there more different packages you have installed, the more complicated it becomes. often these upgrades will require user-interaction in order to get the services to run again (mostly updating the configurations; upgrades of default-configurations usually work out of the box, but if you have customized a given configuration a lot, chances arre that you will have to touch those files again).

now *Ubuntu* is a Debian derivative so many things apply here as well.
unfortunately Ubuntu does not pay as close attention to "safe upgrades" as Debian.

therefore i'd say that **no, there is no easy way** esp. if you are totally new to linux administration.

Comment: But the OP is not trying to upgrade, they've switched machines and want to copy all data from the old one to the new.

Comment: @terdon true; but for migrating the data, he still has to upgrade the data (in the case of e.g. databases); the Debian upgrade mechanisms take care of that.

Comment: Between different _machines_? How? Are you suggesting he first upgrade the old machine (twice) just in order to be able to copy to the new one?